# Immutable.js update a value multiple key in Map

Tags: react-redux, immutable.js

I am trying to use Immutable.js. So I used the Map object and I have a 2 fields for ex.

```
const initialState = Map({
    isUserAuthorized : false,
    pending : false
});
```

and I want to update both. How I can do that? I tried to use a standard  Update method like that:

```
state.update( "isUserAuthorized", () => true, "pending", () => false);
```

But it isn't working somehow. So I have only one idea - update only particular key and after that do the same with other and return a result.

But I think it is a not so perfect idea. Maybe other normal variants exist? Thanks for any help!

P.S.  I found that it can be done via **set** and **withMutations** like:

```
initialState.withMutations(map => {
            map.set("isUserAuthorized", true).set("pending", false);
        })
```

But is it really so hard to update multiple values in Map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [.set()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/set):

```
const initialState = Map({
    isUserAuthorized : false,
    pending : false
});

initialState = initialState.set('isUserAuthorized', true);
initialState = initialState.set('pending', false);
```

If you don't want to repeat it. You can create a function to pass multiple params.

Another way is with [.merge()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/merge):

```
const newState = initialState.merge({
    isUserAuthorized: true, 
    pending: false
});
```

Or chaining multiple sets:

```
initialState = initialState.set('isUserAuthorized', true)
    .set('pending', false)
    .set('key3', 'value3');
```

Comment: Hi Albert! Thank you for your answer. But, actually, is it possible to do it in one row? like
set('isUserAuthorized' , 1).set('pending', z)

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a stale post but in case this helps anyone else, I just had to figure this out yesterday. Here is what I ended up doing.

If you want to change *all* the keys to be the same then you can map.

```
const initialState = Map({
  isUserAuthorized : false,
  pending : false
});

const newState = initialState.map(() => true)
// { isUserAuthorized: true, pending: true }
```

If there's specific keys you want to set then add a condition or ternary expression in your map and only update what's relevant. Here's a quick and dirty example.

```
const initialState = Map({
  isUserAuthorized : false,
  pending : false,
  dontChangeMe: false
});

const newState = initialState.map((val, key) => (
  key === 'isUserAuthorized' || key === 'pending' ? true : value
)
// { isUserAuthorized: true, pending: true, dontChangeMe: false }
```

If you want to get clever and make things reusable you could make a curried utility to pass in a list of the target keys, then just invoke with the value you want them to be.